# CoreBluetooth / CBATTErrorDomain Code=6 "The request is not supported."

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

While working with `CoreBluetooth`, reading the value of a charactetistic, I hit an error in the *peripheral(_:didUpdateValueFor:error:)* function of the `CBPeripheralDelegate` protocol.

I keep getting this message in the debugging console:

```
Error in peripheral(_:didUpdateValueFor:error:) :
Error Domain=CBATTErrorDomain Code=6 "The request is not supported."
      UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The request is not supported.}
```

Everything I have tried at this point to solve the issue failed.

Has anyone had such an experience and found a solution?

Here is some of the relevant code:

```
// CBPeripheralDelegate protocol implementation.

func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {
    print(#function)
    if error != nil {
        print("Error in \(#function) :\n\(error!)")
        return
    }

    for service in peripheral.services ?? [] {
        print("Discovered service \(service)")
        if service.uuid == service_UUID {
            peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for: service)
            //peripheral.discoverCharacteristics([svcCharac_UUID], for: service) (Same problem!)
        }
    }
}


func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor
    service: CBService, error: Error?) {
    print(#function)
    if error != nil {
        print("Error in \(#function) :\n\(error!)")
        return
    }

    for characteristic in service.characteristics ?? [] {
        print("Discovered characteristic \(characteristic)")
        if characteristic.uuid ==  svcCharac_UUID {
            peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: characteristic)
            peripheral.readValue(for: characteristic)
        }
    }
}


func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral,
                didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic,
                error: Error?) {
    print(#function)
    if error != nil {
        print("Error in \(#function) :\n\(error!)")
        return
    }

    .................
}
```

Here is the chunk of code in the peripheral app where the characteristic is created:

```
//Class level declarations:

var cbPerifMngr:CBPeripheralManager!, mutaSRVC:CBMutableService!,
svcCharac:CBMutableCharacteristic!

.........

// CBPeripheralManagerDelegate protocol implementation.

func peripheralManagerDidUpdateState(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager) {
    print(#function)
    if peripheral.state == .poweredOn {
        mutaSRVC = CBMutableService(type: service_UUID, primary: true)
        svcCharac = CBMutableCharacteristic(type: svcCharac_UUID,
                                            properties: [.read, .notify],
                                            value: Data(base64Encoded: "Hello!"),//nil,//
                                            permissions: .readable)
        mutaSRVC.characteristics = [svcCharac]
        cbPerifMngr?.add(mutaSRVC)
        cbPerifMngr?.publishL2CAPChannel(withEncryption: false)
    }
}
```

Comment: In `if characteristic.uuid ==  svcCharac_UUID {`, check its properties. You might not be able to subscribe for notify, or read: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcharacteristicproperties

Comment: In the "peripheral(_:didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor:error:)" function (debugger) I can see:
"Discovered characteristic <CBCharacteristic: 0x281eb8060, UUID = BE8E633D-1FE1-4B74-BUG2-EDD0E74347E0, properties = 0x12, value = (null), notifying = NO>". Could that be the explanation?

Comment: But it is set with "properties: [.read, .notify]". I am missing something here.

Comment: Is your peripheral also an iOS app? If so, show how you create the characteristic on the peripheral side.

Comment: Yes it is. I just modified my post to include the information you need.

Comment: Remove the fixed value from your characteristic.  And specify `nil` as per your commented code.

Comment: I just tried following your suggestion. Unfortunately it does not work, I get the exact same error as before. And I can also see "notifying = NO" right before, if that is related.

Comment: I finally solved the problem. I needed to get rid of the line "peripheral.readValue(for: characteristic)".
Beside I also found out that the update (of the characteristic value) was not performed on the peripheral side. Once all that set, it started to work as expected.

Comment: #michel Can you please help me I am getting Error Domain=CBATTErrorDomain Code=6 "The request is not supported." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The request is not supported

Comment: @sarit bahuguna. Sorry for my late answer. That was a while ago. But by reading the post again and the comments I can see some trace of my solution. See the comment starting with "I finally solved the problem. I needed to get rid of the....", this should tell you how I solved the issue at the time myself. I hope this helps.